# Error trying to create sift - Module has no attribute - Python

Tags: python, image-processing, computer-vision, opencv

I am trying to do this in python, but I get this error and I do not really understand why:

This is what I have:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

img1 = cv2.imread('or1.jpg', 0)      
img2 = cv2.imread('dm1.jpg', 0) 

sift = cv2.SIFT()
kp1, des1 = sift.detectAndCompute(img1, None)
kp2, des2 = sift.detectAndCompute(img2, None)
bf = cv2.BFMatcher()
matches = bf.knnMatch(des1, des2, k=2)
good = []

for m, n in matches:
    if m.distance < 0.75 * n.distance:
        good.append([m])

img3 = cv2.drawMatchesKnn(img1, kp1, img2, kp2, good, flags=2)
plt.imshow(img3), plt.show()
```

And this is the error I have.

```
sift = cv2.SIFT_create() AttributeError: module 'cv2.cv2' has no attribute 'SIFT_create'
```

Can someone help me understand what am I doing wrong?

Comment: PLEASE format your code and explain your problem in detail in the section, not only in the title!

Comment: now its fine? Actually the problem is the error of about  sift

Comment: I can do it for you but you should learn! Edit the post, select all the code you have and press "ctrl+k". If you have code then normal text then code, select part by part, and "ctrl + k". 
At the beginning of  your code explain what are you trying to do, and at the end what is wrong and why you think its wrong

Comment: Only you plz tell me what is this error "module 'cv2.cv2' has no attribute 'SIFT_create' " how can i reduce this ??

Comment: Is there any other call stack information you can provide?  I am not sure if this SIFT_create() call is originating from within your module or internally.  If it is coming from your module, could you please show where a method entitled SIFT_create() is being called.  (I see a call to a sift constructor, but I am not sure where SIFT_create comes from since the alias to a constructor in Python is obj.__init__)